# getRange & setValue setting the wrong values

Tags: google-apps-script

Apologies, I only have basic knowledge of script

I am trying to use a script that when a form response is submitted, it copies three of the columns to another sheet depending on what the input it

For example if the answer to the second question was apples, it will send it to the spreadsheet dedicated to apples and so on

There are over 25 fields on the form but I only want to select columns 2, 3 & 4

The code I have been using sends the data but it sends column 2 in 3 columns rather than 2,3 & 4

For example:

Instead of sending

X     Y     Z

It sends

X     X     X

Here is a copy of the code:

```js
function myspliFunction() {

  var Apples = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SheetID').getSheetByName('Sheet1')  
  var Oranges = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SheetID').getSheetByName('Sheet1')  
  var Form = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Form responses 3')  
  var site = Form.getRange(Form.getLastRow(), 4).getValue();  

  if (site == 'Apples'){
    var getApples = Form.getRange(Form.getLastRow(), 1, 1, 3).getValues();

    Apples.getRange(Apples.getLastRow()+1, 2, 1, 3).setValue(getApples);
  }
  if (site == 'Oranges'){
    var getOranges = Form.getRange(Form.getLastRow(), 2, 1, Form.getLastColumn()).getValues();

    Oranges.getRange(Oranges.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 3).setValue(getOranges);
  }
}
```

Comment: Since you're using `getValues()` you should be using `setValues()` not `setValue()`, note the plurality.

Comment: Sorry, silly mistake my end, thanks for spotting this for me!